# Kafka - error when producing from command line (character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I spinned on my laptop a Kafka in Docker (with docker-compose).

After that, created new kafka topic with:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181  --create --topic simple    --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

(did not create schema in Schema Registry yet).

Now trying to produce (based on this example - step 3 - https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.0/quickstart.html):

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
         --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic simple \
         --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'
```

Entering value:

```
{"f1": "value1"}
```

Error:

```
{"f1": "value1"}
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:191)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:218)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:307)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:299)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:294)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:100)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readMessage(AvroMessageReader.java:166)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:59)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
```

How to solve this? 
Can it be because Kafka cluster uses SSL but error is bogus?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`kafka-avro-console-producer`, by default, assumes that Schema Registry is listening at port `http://localhost:8081`. However, if another process is listening to that port, weird errors might occur.

In order to overcome this issue, you can specify the schema URL when running the producer using `--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:18081`

For example,

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
         --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic simple \
         --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}' \
         --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:18081
```

Comment: Thanks. My Schema Registry (for local Docker) was on `localhost:8080`. Added that and now getting new errors: `ERROR Error when sending message to topic simple with key: null, value: 12 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback:52)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [simple]` . I am guessing that since this is Docker with SSL that ACLs should be enabled or a config parameter file passed...

Comment: @Joe I think it might be better to open a separate question for this new error you get!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but the solution was different in my case. I am posting here in case someone else finds this useful.

This error is about accessing the schema registry and the expected response. So either the configuration is not correct and the client cannot assess the schema registry or the response is not recognised.

1. So, check that you provide the correct configuration, `--property schema.registry.url` in this case as [Giorgos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49995042/550155) mentioned. See also: https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.1/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html
2. You can also `curl` the schema registry to see if you get any response, like

   ```sh
   curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects
   ```

   See also: https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.1/schema-registry/develop/using.html

---

3. In my case the problem was a web proxy that filtered the traffic. So check:

   - `NO_PROXY`, `no_proxy` as well as
   - `HTTP_PROXY`, `http_proxy` and
   - `HTTPS_PROXY`, `https_proxy`

   to ensure that nothing intercepts the call to the registry. If you are creating a jvm application then the corresponding flags are:

   - `http.nonProxyHosts`,
   - `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`, or
   - `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort`.