# Not able to write AVRO object to another topic using kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I have a kafka streams app, which reads an AVRO message do some transformation on it and then write it to another topic. I can able to read AVRO message without any issues but while writing to another topic, I am getting the following error. This particular error code is nowhere found in the internet.

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"Value","namespace":"com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.model","fields":[{"name":"StoreId","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"TransactionId","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"TransactiontimestampArchivo","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Transactiontimestamp","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Itembarcode","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Iteminternalcode","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Itemdescription","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Itemsalevolume","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Itemunitprice","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Itemtotalsale","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"Transactiontotalsale","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"ItemCategory","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"IsWeight","type":["null","string"],"default":null}],"connect.name":"com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.model.Value"}
>   Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Here is [a thread](https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor/issues/148) which talks about the very same error code, but someone concluded the thread relates this issue with Authentication. Currently the schema registry that we are running, we haven't secured it. It is a plain dev server with no such security.

Comment: Can you register the schema manually or use its rest api normally otherwise? That error is multiple places, too for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992301/kafka-error-when-producing-from-command-line-character-code-60-expec

Comment: The `<` implies that there may be a reverse proxy in between your application and the schema registry that is serving some HTML to tell you about some error.  Try to replicate (or debug) the HTTP request your application is making to the schema registry so you can see exactly what the response is, and it should be more obvious what the issue is.